# what can I do to be member of the ubuntu community?

Tags: installation

I want to be member of the ubuntu community.What can I do,please help me

Comment: hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can become one of the Ubuntu Member with many ways of contributions.

1. In Ask Ubuntu helping others with answers and earning some Reputation and then apply to Ubuntu Membership.
2. Join in Ubuntuforums and then do postings , earn some beans and there also you can apply for Ubuntu Membership.
3. Join in Ubuntu Bug Squad , Testing Team, Ubuntu +1 and do some work & through that also you can get Ubuntu Membership.

[image]

Some super links for you

1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership/NewMember.
2. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Forums/Membership
3. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership